# Android: how to know if button is held down

Tags: android, button, user-interface, callback

I am playing with a game on Android, and I have a function MoveCharacter (int direction) that moves an animated sprite when buttons are pressed

For example, when user presses up I have this code:

```
 mControls.UpButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLevel.mCharAnimation.FrameUp();
            }           
        });
```

However, I’d like to be able to keep moving the character as long as the user keeps the button down.
Surprisingly, I have not found out how to do this in Android. 
Is there some kind of onButtonDownLister?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) to have separate actions for down, up, and other states.

```
mControls.UpButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // Do something
            return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // No longer down
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this really doesn't answer the question. if the user slides his finger off the button, ACTION_UP is never called.

Comment: @quemeful, would have been nice if you posted a solution that _does_ answer the question.  Since you comment actually lead me to test that scenario I found the correct answer is to also test for `MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL` and do the same thing as action_up.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments by Gary Bak you would want to detect if the user drags their finger outside the button also.

```
mButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Pressed down
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Released
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                // Released - Dragged finger outside
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [onTouchListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html). Basically, this will allow you to see when the object is touched, see how the user is moving their finger, and know when the let go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnTouchListener` instead

```
mControls.UpButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mLevel.mCharAnimation.FrameUp();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // User released the button, do your stuff here
                    break;
                }
                return false;

            }           
        });
```